# Mock controller with an object parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, controller, mockmvc

I'm trying to test a method with this signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Employee/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT, consumes="application/json") 
@Transactional
public @ResponseBody Map update(@PathVariable Integer id, 
    @RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> information) {

}
```

The problem is that MockMvc param attributes accept only String parameters, is there a way to pass a `HashMap` or an instance class object to the RequestBody  as parameter?

When I try to pass a `HashMap` as a string, I get a MismatchException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Jackson for this. The idea is to deserialize your objects (doesn't matter that it's HashMap) into JSON string and pass it into MockMvc.

[Here is tutorial how to do that](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/). Just search for TestClass there and take a look how it is used. Skip the unit testing of GET requests.